# Where did my bounty disappear?

Tags: support, bounty

I set a bounty for one of my question (100 points). I did not receive the answer I hoped after 9 days. StackExchange.com mentions in such case the answerer who has more upvotes will receive half of my bounty. The other half will come back to me. But I guess in my case no answerer received half of my bounty , nor I received back the other half. The bounty disappeared. Why ?
This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257802/how-to-browse-a-whole-website-using-selenium) I set a bounty of 100 points on it

Comment: What question??  If it was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257802/how-to-browse-a-whole-website-using-selenium), then the bounty [ended](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24257802/revisions) with no answer being selected.

Comment: You didn't select an answer to award the bounty to so the 100 points are gone.  You have to award the bounty in the timeframe given, if you wait too long then you can no longer award it.

Comment: But it is stated the answerer who had more upvotes will receive half of it, but no answerer did

Comment: Only on answers given _after_ the bounty starts.  I'd suggest reading about [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and how it works.

Comment: "The other half will come back to me." Are you sure about that?

Comment: @ChrisF I think I misunderstood the rules. Detailed explanation is the one I accepted below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) you offered [*disappeared*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24257802/revisions) because you didn't award the bounty to any of the answers to your question.

You have 7 days to award the bounty and it will be manually awarded:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created **after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2** will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

The answers to your question that have a score of 2 were given before you started the bounty on June 19 and the answers that came in after the start didn't meet the criteria to be automatically awarded 1/2 of the bounty. Since you had no winning or selected answer the 100 points offered are gone.

Comment: Just to be clear, you might want to add that the bounty is entirely lost to the giver regardless of award/no award - that was part of the confusion from the question, I think.